# Aplicar loop for dentro de uma lista com uma função com argumento de grupo

Tags: r, lista

Tenho estes dados:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 3, expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100), simplify = TRUE
  ), 
  y = as.factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE))
)
```

E esta lista:

```
lt_1 <- split(
  x = df_1, 
  f = df_1[['y']]
)

names(lt_1) <- paste('df', seq_along(lt_1), sep = '_')
names(lt_1)
```

Quero aplicar a função `pairwise.t.test` para cada `df` desta lista. Tentei:

```
for (i in lt_1) {
  for (f in names(i[, 1:3])) {
    print(pairwise.t.test(x = lt_1[, f], g = lt_1[['y']], p.adj = 'bonferroni'))
  }
}
```

> Error in lt_1[, f] : incorrect number of dimensions

Sem sucesso.

Esta função tem um argumento de grupo (`g`). Talvez o problema esteja ali, acredito eu.

Comment: Quando você está aplicando o teste, o 'g' só possui um fator, o que inviabiliza o teste.

Comment: Se a dúvida se mantém com as listas podemos criar um exemplo em que faça sentido no contexto do teste. O problema estava nas listas ou no teste?

Comment: Eu forneci um exemplo errado. Há apenas um fator nas listas. Na verdade, é um erro de digitação. Podem fechar a pergunta. Agradeço a todos pela atenção e perdão pelo equívoco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do está no `x` e no `g`, você deve substituir o `lt_1` por `i`:

```
for (i in lt_1) {
for (f in names(i[, 1:3])) {
    print(pairwise.t.test(x = i[, f], g = i[['y']], p.adj = 'bonferroni'))
  }
}
```

Entretanto, para os dados que você está utilizando, nenhuma matriz é gerada, pois a variável resposta `y` é um factor de apenas 1 valor. Para gerar a tabela é preciso que a variável resposta tenha pelo menos mais 1 valor.

Comment: Filipe Lauar, Não funciona. Veja: `<0 x 0 matrix>`

Comment: Mas o que você quer que retorne? O ajuste que eu fiz foi para você utilizar a estrutura correta. A variavel `i` corresponde a cada data.frame da variavel `lt_1` e `f`é a coluna do data.frame.

Comment: Tem que retornar os `p-values` de cada comparação de grupos. E não tem retorno nenhum. Se a função for aplicada em `df_1`, funciona.

Comment: Mas o erro então está na lógica, eu apenas arrumei o erro do seu código. Você quer encontrar o p_value de cada uma das colunas "x.1" "x.2" "x.3" relacionando-as coluna "y"?

Comment: Isso. Mas não retorna nada.

Comment: Talvez seja porque a variavel `g`seja um factor de apenas 1 valor.

Comment: Testei aqui incluir novos valores na coluna `y` e o data.frame é gerado. Vou atualizar a minha resposta explicando isso.

Comment: Tem toda razão. Eu errei no exemplo. Dividi por grupos, e cada `df` ficou com um grupo só. Perdão. Pode atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Se compreendi a pergunta, não é necessário o `split`, basta passar o fator `y` a cada teste.

```
t_tests <- lapply(names(df_1)[1:3], function(nms){
  pairwise.t.test(df_1[[nms]], df_1[['y']], p.adjust.method = 'bonferroni')
})

t_tests  
#[[1]]
#
#   Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#
#data:  df_1[[nms]] and df_1[["y"]] 
#
#  1 2
#2 1 -
#3 1 1
#
#P value adjustment method: bonferroni 
#
#[[2]]
#
#   Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#
#data:  df_1[[nms]] and df_1[["y"]] 
#
#  1    2   
#2 0.79 -   
#3 1.00 1.00
#
#P value adjustment method: bonferroni 
#
#[[3]]
#
#   Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#
#data:  df_1[[nms]] and df_1[["y"]] 
#
#  1    2   
#2 1.00 -   
#3 1.00 0.89
#
#P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```